# Android getting the view tree

Tags: android, user-interface, view

I want to get all views inside of an activity. like;

```
ArrayList<View> views = new Arraylist<>();

views.addAll(getAllViewsFromActivity());
```

what I want is "getAllViewsFromActivity()" function. I clearly want to get all the views even a single button. But I couldn't find any clear answer.

For the progress, it must be like this:

```
                         MainView : getWindow().getDecorView()
                   -                                                  -
          RelativeLayout
        -                - 
   Button              LinearLayout
                               -
                               TextView
```

How can I get this tree in Android programmatically? and also lets assume that I got this tree, Can I also identify the types of them like: view instanceof Button ?

Comment: it can get by getChild, but it will a deep loop. why you want to get it, maybe we should change the way to the aim

Comment: @Lenoarod I have bad coded project and I don't want to go through all the design. Design is in 3 colors, black white and gray, I just want to make the colors viceversa. Just wanna set opposite colors.

Comment: according to you describe I give an answer, you can try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the view you want to get is clear. so you can use the parent view(such as LinerarLayout) to get the children. so you can try this:

```
int count = parent.getChildCount();
for(int i =0; i< count;i++){
   View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
   //here you can to chage the view some proper. 
   //if you only want to change the background color, it belongs to view, don't 
   // need to cast.
}
```